# How to add index support to a struct/tuples with homogeneous types?

Tags: struct, types, rust

I'm interested to add support for indexing a struct or tuple, even though its possible to use dot syntax `mytuple.0` for example, I would like to be able to use a variable to access the index, eg: `mytuple[i]`,

looking at the documentation, it seems this is supported, eg:

```
use std::ops::Index;

struct Vector(f64, f64);

impl Index<usize> for Vector {
    type Output = f64;

    fn index(&self, _index: usize) -> f64 {
        match _index {
            0 => self.0,
            1 => self.1,
            _ => panic!("invalid index: {:?}", index)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = Vector(5.0, 5.0);
    for i in 0..2 {
        println!("value {} at index {}\n", v[i], i);
    }
}
```

However I get this error:

```
src/main.rs:8:9: 14:10 error: method `index` has an incompatible type for trait:
 expected &-ptr,
    found f64 [E0053]
src/main.rs:8         fn index(&self, _index: usize) -> f64 {
```

Whats the best way to make structs/tuples support indexing?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is *exactly* what the compiler is telling you: you're trying to change the definition of the `Index` trait.  You're not allowed to do that.  Look again at the definition:

```rust
pub trait Index<Idx> where Idx: ?Sized {
    type Output: ?Sized;
    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output;
}
```

Specifically, look at the return type of `index`: `&Output`.  If `Output` is `f64`, then the result of `index` **must** be `&f64`, no ifs, ands, or buts.  This is what the error message is telling you:

```
method `index` has an incompatible type for trait: expected &-ptr, found f64
```

There is also the larger explanation you get if you ask the compiler to [explain that error code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0053):

````
> rustc --explain E0053
The parameters of any trait method must match between a trait implementation
and the trait definition.

Here are a couple examples of this error:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(x: u16);
    fn bar(&self);
}

struct Bar;

impl Foo for Bar {
    // error, expected u16, found i16
    fn foo(x: i16) { }

    // error, values differ in mutability
    fn bar(&mut self) { }
}
```
````

The solution is to not change the trait and return a borrowed pointer as required:

```
impl Index<usize> for Vector {
    type Output = f64;

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &f64 {
        match index {
            0 => &self.0,
            1 => &self.1,
            _ => panic!("invalid index: {:?}", index)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, to preempt a likely follow-up question: *no,* you *cannot* have indexing return a value.